# Gnome3 runs faster when running game

Tags: command-line, gnome, performance

I'm having a bizarre, and kind of funny, "problem"(if you can call it such). Ordinarily, Gnome shell is quite choppy on my system. Sure, it's smooth "enough" and fast "enough" but it most certainly isn't much of a joy to use, especially when compared to eOS's Pantheon, though it still beats Unity performance wise.

I noticed the other day that while running a 3D game in fullscreen, Gnome Shells's performance improves dramatically. Not only is the interface twice as smooth, but applications load faster as well. There's still a bit of stutter here and there, but the difference is like night and day.

My question is this: Is there any way to reach this performance level without having to run a game in the background at all times? My PC has a Haswell i5 with HD4600 graphics, my OS is Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 running Gnome 3.10, and I have the latest mesa drivers, if that's any help.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be that the game triggers the graphics out of a power save mode or something... I just wish it was faster ALL OF THE TIME myself...

Comment: You and me both. :(

Comment: Does your system have a discrete graphics card?